# Create a jQuery screensaver with delay and a warning message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a screensaver on my website. So the breakdown of the request is as follow:

1. Detect `onload`, clicks and touches and start a timer that counts 5
   seconds. Every time it detects the `onload`, clicks and touches it
   resets the timer to start over again.
2. After 5 seconds it gives you a warning that tells you that in 5
   seconds the screensaver will initiate.
3. Screensaver starts and when it is clicks it returns to the homepage,
   starting the process from the start again.

Issues:

- I am having issues with the javascript `setInterval` and
  `clearInterval` functions, which is causing the counters to run over
  each other so I assume I might be using them in the wrong places.
- I am getting thousands of "Touched" logged to the console which
  indicates that it is firing up after the `$( 'body' ).bind(
  'touchstart click', function(event)` event, which I cannot
  understand.

Here is my javascript code:

```
// Start screensaver in the background
var ss1 = setInterval(function() {
    $('#screensaver > div:first')
    .animate( { opacity: 0 }, 1000 )
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#screensaver');
    console.log("screensaver cycles every 2 seconds");
},  2000);
// End of section -- Start screensaver in the background

$( 'body' ).bind( 'touchstart click', function(event) {

    console.log( 'Touched' );    
    var timeoutVar = setInterval( function(){

        $( '#screensaver_warning_button' ).trigger( 'click' );
        clearInterval( timeoutVar );

        var secondTimeoutVar = setInterval(function(){

            $( '#screensaver' ).show();
            clearInterval( secondTimeoutVar );

        }, 5000);

    }, 5000);

});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="index.html">
    <div id="screensaver" class="screensaver">
      <div><img src="img/landing-bg_1.jpg" alt="text" /></div>
      <div><img src="img/landing-bg_2.jpg" alt="text" /></div>
      <div><img src="img/landing-bg_3.jpg" alt="text" /></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

And the modal that warns that the screensaver should come up (I am using Bootstrap):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="screensaver_warning" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h1>Screensaver will start soon, if you would like to continue, please press the button below.</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciate with this thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try  this , hope it helps :

```
$( 'body' ).bind( 'touchstart click', function(event) {

    console.log( 'Touched' );    
    setTimeout( function(){

        $( '#screensaver_warning_button' ).trigger( 'click' );
        setTimeout(function(){
            $( '#screensaver' ).show();
        }, 5000);
    }, 5000);
});
```

PS : you should start your screensaver when its time not at strart at it will always be running

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is still giving me the same errors and the time outs aren't cleared so it is running the whole thing a sync every time I click.

Comment: sorry i couldnt help , the Timeout runs once and automaticly get cleared not like interval but like i said you should execute setInteral when its due to becouse executing it liek that will make it execute ay lunch and always run (as there is no clearInterval(ss1);)